# MS Excel - Consolidate and sum from columns with data validation list and dependent list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, excel-2016

I have an excel sheet consist with 3 columns: Price, Category1, Category2.

Category1 is a select-drop down using data validation list from predefined name (from another sheet).

Category2 is also a drop down list from defined names but with dependency of Category1 using the INDIRECT function.

I would like to create cells with data of a the total amount (Sum Prices) for Category1 and Category2.

For Example:

[image: excel example]

So I would get the sum: A 350, B 400, A1 200 and so on...

Consolidate column Category1/Category2 did not work for me (got a message: no data was consolidate), Pivote table wizard also did not work (got a pivot table with all data messed up)

Any Ideas?

Comment: `SUMIFS()`? What have you tried so far?  How do you figure though `450` for `A`? I show `100 + 150 + 100`, totaling `350`?

Comment: fixed the 450 to 350

Comment: how can I use SUMIF for dynamic lists? the list can change. can you provide with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple pivot table should give the correct numbers, even if they aren't the numbers you want:

[image]

Comment: It seems to give the data, but the pivot table is not dynamic, so if I change the value of a cell to a different list item, I need to recreate the pivot table. any ideas how to make if work?

Comment: @arielmorry As far as I know, you can't set a pivot table to auto refresh.  (It only needs to be refreshed, not recreated.)  You will need to use VBA if you want that to happen.

Comment: Could you create a Worksheet_Change event on the "Sheet1" to refresh the pivot table on Sheet2 when something changes perhaps?

Comment: @BruceWayne - yes, that was the sort of thing I was thinking of.  Hopefully the OP will attempt that and post a question if they get stuck.  (I didn't want to give a VBA solution on how to create a dynamic update, when the question doesn't ask for it and doesn't include a VBA tag.)

Comment: I have zero knowledge in VBA, if you can paste the code to do what @bruceWayne suggested, I'll give it a shot. Regardless, your answer is correct and I accepted it. thanks!